# Any fancy way to unwind Enum classes in python?

Tags: python, enums

I am currently coding a package that contains several `Enum` classes and would like to use the symbolic names directly from the package name, not from the classes themselves, as OpenCV does. Is there anyway to define the classes but still accessing their symbolic names directly from the package or shall I directly hardcode them in the package's `__init__.py` ?

For now I am currently in this state:

```py
from enum import Enum

class enum_class1(Enum):
    class1_sym1: int = 0
    class1_sym2: int = 1
    class1_sym3: int = 2

class enum_class2(Enum):
    class2_sym1: int = 0
    class2_sym2: int = 1
    class2_sym3: int = 2
```

What I am currently doing :

```py
import mypackage as p

state = p.enum_class2.class_2_sim1
```

What I would like to rather do :

```py
import mypackage as p

state = p.class_2_sim1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of compromising static analysis, you can automatically define global variables for each Enum member (as suggested in [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76057665/11082165)) by taking advantage of the [`Enum.__members__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-dunder-names) mapping. Given

```
class enum_class1(Enum):
    class1_sym1: int = 0
    class1_sym2: int = 1
    class1_sym3: int = 2
```

we have

```
>>> enum_class1.__members__
mappingproxy({'class1_sym1': <enum_class1.class1_sym1: 0>,
              'class1_sym2': <enum_class1.class1_sym2: 1>,
              'class1_sym3': <enum_class1.class1_sym3: 2>})
```

This mapping can be used to populate the module's [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) as

```
globals().update(enum_class1.__members__)
```

So,

```
class enum_class1(Enum):
    class1_sym1: int = 0
    class1_sym2: int = 1
    class1_sym3: int = 2

globals().update(enum_class1.__members__)

print(repr(class1_sym1))
```

works as expected, and will print

```
<enum_class1.class1_sym1: 0>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply define global variables with the enum values:

```
from enum import Enum

class enum_class1(Enum):
    class1_sym1: int = 0
    class1_sym2: int = 1
    class1_sym3: int = 2

class1_sym1: int = enum_class1.class1_sym1
class1_sym2: int = enum_class1.class1_sym2
class1_sym3: int = enum_class1.class1_sym3

class enum_class2(Enum):
    class2_sym1: int = 0
    class2_sym2: int = 1
    class2_sym3: int = 2

class2_sym1: int = enum_class2.class2_sym1
class2_sym2: int = enum_class2.class2_sym2
class2_sym3: int = enum_class2.class2_sym3
```

Comment: I guess this just comes from copying, but the annotations are incorrect, `class1_sym1: int = enum_class1.class_sym1` -> `class1_sym1: enum_class1 = enum_class1.class_sym1` or just omit them altogether since the type should be inferable.

Answer (score 1):

A more dynamic approach that leverages the `__getattr__` in a module would be something like this:

```py
from enum import Enum

class enum_class1(Enum):
    class1_sym1: int = 0
    class1_sym2: int = 1
    class1_sym3: int = 2

class enum_class2(Enum):
    class2_sym1: int = 0
    class2_sym2: int = 1
    class2_sym3: int = 2


def __getattr__(target):
    target_cls, target_attr = target.rsplit('_', 1)
    if (cls := globals().get(f'enum_{target_cls}')) is not None:
        return getattr(cls, f'{target_cls}_{target_attr}')
```

```py
In [1]: import mypackage as p

In [2]: p.class2_sym1
Out[2]: <enum_class2.class2_sym1: 0>
```

Comment: This implementation has some interesting side affects, namely `p.doesnotexist` will raise a `ValueError`, and `p._doesnotexist` will evaluate to `None` while both should normally raise an `AttributeError`. It's also worth noting that this also only works when the attributes are looked up on the module object, and won't work when the globals mapping is searched directly. So, for example, those "globals" won't be available inside functions in the same module.

Answer (score 1):

If all your enum members have different names, you can do:

```
from enum import Enum, global_enum

@global_enum
class enum_class1(Enum):
    class1_sym1: int = 0
    class1_sym2: int = 1
    class1_sym3: int = 2
```

Now you can access from the module, and the repr is updated to not show the class:

```
>>> import mypackage as p
>>> state = p.class1_sym1
>>> state
mypackage.class1_sym1
```

You can, of course, write your own `__repr__` if you don't like the default.

Also, if you need to appease a linter, add

```
class1_sym1 = class1_sym2 = class1_sym3 = None
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.